# autologin console as root on fedora

Tags: fedora, scripting, login, autologin, console

Can someone help to autologin in console text mode as root in fedora, usually I can do using script like this :

`/sbin/autologin.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
0</dev/$1 1>/dev/$1 2>&1
cat /etc/issue
shift
exec $*
```

and on `/etc/inittab` do login by calling that script

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/autologin.sh tty1 login -f root
..
..
```

now I can't do that, since fedora use /etc/init/tty.conf :

```
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
instance $TTY
exec /sbin/mingetty $TTY
```

I know its dangerous to autologin and moreover as root, but I don't care, I don't care about security.

Comment: On most Linux installations, considering the root user "secure" is a bit of a mistake. In fact, if you have physical access to the console, and can reboot it manually, gaining access to a root shell is as easy as adjusting the kernel boot parameters, and many distros provide a "recovery mode" boot option that does it for you. The root account can be considered secure against *remote* users on a server, but you need an encrypted drive to make it secure against a local user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line to "/etc/init/tty.conf":

```
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin root $TTY
```